# Force a View on the bottom of ScrollView if content height less than screen height

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with some Views in it. I want to force the last view to be on bottom if ScrollView's content height is less than screen height. How do I do that?

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View ... />

            <View ... />

            <View ... />

            <View ... /> // this one should be on bottom if LinearLayout's contents don't exceed screen height
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried using relative layout and giving the property "align_parentBottom" = true ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add following code

```
       <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

before button view that you want to bottom of linnerLayout

+

change layout_height of LinearLayout to match_parent

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
```

+

add `android:fillViewport="true"` to scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: This solution seems to work well, however I do get the following layout design view warning when using both LinearLayout and RelativeLayout as the root child of the ScrollView

This LinearLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height attributes to wrap_content rather than fill_parent or match_parent in the scrolling dimension  

Issue id: ScrollViewSize

It makes sense what the warning is saying - why would you want to create a scroll view with children that match parent height. how has this worked for others?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

**Screen shot**

[image]

**xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Some views" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Click" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RelativeLayout` as a Root child of `ScrollView` with `android:fillViewport="true"`.below is an example.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/txt1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class below instead of LinearLayout inside your ScrollView. It will align the object at the bottom of the LinearLayout to the bottom if content is less than ScrollView height. I wrote this with Kotlin, please improve my answer if you convert it to Java.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout

class ResizingLinearLayout: LinearLayout {

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        val targetChild = getChildAt(this.childCount - 1)
        val parentScrollViewHeight = (parent!! as View).height
        val childParams = targetChild.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        val addHeight = kotlin.math.max(parentScrollViewHeight - kotlin.math.max(oldh, h - childParams.topMargin), 0)
        if(targetChild.height > 0) {
            childParams.topMargin = addHeight
            targetChild.layoutParams = childParams
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h + addHeight, oldw, oldh)
        } else {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        }
    }
}
```